# Data not passing via JQuery AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am frustrated with this and can't get the data to pass.  Firebug has been showing me

letter=

I have tried

```
data: {letter: alpha},
```

AND

```
data:"letter=" + alpha,
```

with no success.

Script below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#alphaFilter a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var alpha = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {letter: alpha},
            url: "includes/filterPlants.php",
            success: function(update){
                $('#plants').html(update);
            }
        });
    });
})
```

My HTML element below (basically I want to filter the data set without page refresh):

```
<div id="alphaFilter">
    <a href="#" value="All">All</a>
    <a href="#" value="A">A</a>
    <a href="#" value="B">B</a>
    <a href="#" value="C">C</a>
    <a href="#" value="D">D</a>
    <a href="#" value="E">E</a>
    <a href="#" value="F">F</a>
    <a href="#" value="G">G</a>
    <a href="#" value="H">H</a>
    <a href="#" value="I">I</a>
    <a href="#" value="J">J</a>
    <a href="#" value="K">K</a>
    <a href="#" value="L">L</a>
    <a href="#" value="M">M</a>
    <a href="#" value="N">N</a>
    <a href="#" value="O">O</a>
    <a href="#" value="P">P</a>
    <a href="#" value="Q">Q</a>
    <a href="#" value="R">R</a>
    <a href="#" value="S">S</a>
    <a href="#" value="T">T</a>
    <a href="#" value="U">U</a>
    <a href="#" value="V">V</a>
    <a href="#" value="W">W</a>
    <a href="#" value="X">X</a>
    <a href="#" value="Y">Y</a>
    <a href="#" value="Z">Z</a>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance, I'm sure this is a pretty easy one for you guys.

Comment: Why do your anchor tags have values? i kinda doubt .val() will work on an anchor tag.

Comment: when debugging, always follow the data to the beginning. The data isn't being sent in ajax, your first step should be to confirm that data exists with `console.log(alpha)`, followed by `console.log($(this).val())`, and then finally `console.log(this.value)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`value` attributes and jQuery's `.val()` are only really meant for `<form>` elements like `<input>`s.

For other element types, you can use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) to store custom information:

```
<a href="#" data-value="A">A</a>
```

And retrieve their values with jQuery's [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var alpha = $(this).data('value');
```

Comment: @JoshBeam: jQuery's `.data()` *does* include `data-*` elements.  http://api.jquery.com/data/#data2

Comment: Yeah, I just saw the documentation.  Looks like the lower-level $.data() won't, but .data() will.  Thanks for the correction @Rocket Hazmat

Comment: @Jonathan Lonowski, thanks this worked, I didn't know .val() was only for form elements. I will accept answer when it lets me and thanks to Kevin B for the console tip!

Answer (score 2):

I believe your HTML is invalid (I don't believe the anchor tag supports a *value* attribute).  In addition, the jQuery *val* method won't grab the contents of the *value* attribute inside your anchor tag.

If you want, you can use the HMLT5 data-* attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-value="A">A</a>
```

```
$(function(){

    $('#alphaFilter a').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var alpha = $(this).attr('data-value');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {letter: alpha},
            url: "includes/filterPlants.php",
            success: function(update){
                $('#plants').html(update);
            }
        });

    });

})
```

**EDIT**
As it has been pointed out in the comments, the jQuery *.data()* method will work for this purpose as well.  Both of these will grab the value of "data-value":

```
$(this).data("value");

//or

$(this).attr("data-value");
```

Comment: You can also do `var alpha = $(this).data('value');`

Comment: It might not be in the [list of standard HTML attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/index/attributes.html) (in fact, it isn't), but it is a valid expando attribute and it is ok to use it. :/ (It is completely valid HTML.)

Comment: @Josh Beam, thanks this works as well appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var alpha = $(this).attr("value")
```

Comment: This might work, but regardless, a _value_ attribute inside of an anchor tag isn't valid HTML.